# What other hidden variables (pre-defined using macros) do I have access to in g++?

Tags: c++, attributes

note: I am using g++ version 4.3.4

So I was learning about assert statements and came across a homebrew assert macro that uses that variables `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` which (cleverly) give the line number and the file name from where they were called -- in this case, from where the assertation failed.  These are epic pieces of information to have!

I was able to infer that the variable `__FUNCTION__` will give you the function name that you are inside of... amazing!!  However, when assert.h is at work, you also get the arguments to the function (i.e. `function: int main(int, char**)` and all I can do currently is get the function name...

Generally speaking, where can I learn more about these wonderful hidden variables and get a complete list of all of them?

p.s.  I guess I understand now why you aren't supposed to use variable names starting with `__`

Comment: you should update your title to better reflect your question. MACRO in g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as getting the function arguments, you can try using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` instead of `__FUNCTION__`.  More information is available here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

As far as a list of pre-defined macros, you can find a lot of them if you hunt around in here:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html#Predefined-Macros

I cannot say with certainty that the list referenced above is complete.  The reason I say this is that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` cannot be found under the list of predefined macros...  why this is, I cannot say.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can find out anything you want about a language by reading its standards document and/or lone implementation's documentation.  In the case of C++, this would currently be ISO/IEC 14882:2003, the 2003 C++ standard.  I don't have a copy, but I do have the C99 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1990), which also lists (in §6.10.8) the magic macros `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`, which expand to strings containing the date & time of the enclosing source file's compilation.  (Also, instead of `__FUNCTION__`, C99 has `__func__` (§6.4.2.2); is the former standard C++ or a compile extension?)

EDIT: The only list of these special names for GCC/G++ that I can find is [this section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html#Function-Names) of the GCC manual, which describes `__func__`, `__FUNCTION__`, and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Comment: I looked in the latest working papers (N3242) and they only list six of them that are manditory.  Plus, another five that are implementation specific.  `__FUNCTION__` cannot be found at all, let alone how to get at the function argument types.  I am looking for a complete list for g++ 4.3.4.

Comment: so you are taking credit for finding `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`? hmm... that doesn't seem right...